# How to get case sensitive file name in PHP?

Tags: php, file, include, file-exists

I've created a function to call file from folder. But the problem is that it is not matching case. My function is

```
function CheckFile($var){
    if($var){
        $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include_folder/'.$var.'.php';
        if (file_exists($file)) {
        return true;
        } 
    } 
}
```

So if file is exists, I include it. Like if $var = profile then it will check in core folder for profile.php and if it exists then it will include it. I am including file when I am calling this function. But the problem is that it is not case sensitive. like if I look for "PrOFile" then it will include profile.php so how to solve this? Please help me if anyone can.

Comment: Don't use Windows to run PHP?

Comment: I amusing xampp to develop my app. And windows 8.

Comment: Try using a regular expression.

Comment: Ideally your development and productions environments should be *identical*. You're not going to be able to get around a core Windows filesystem "feature" without massive amounts of kludging. As well, there are a non-trivial number of ways in which PHP behaves completely differently on Windows vs \*nix. Might I suggest using something like VirtualBox to run a \*nix VM on which to develop?

Comment: I tried a lot. I tried preg_match and preg_match_all. But it didn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use realpath() combined with converting the slashes if needed.

Examples:

```
// Check the filename is the same (don't worry on the path)
if (file_exists($filepath) && basename(realpath($filepath)) === basename($filepath)) {

// Check the full path, converting slashes to be sure
// Assumes final path is Lunix orientated
if (file_exists($filepath) && str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($filepath)) === $filepath) {

// Check the full path, converting slashes to be sure
// Assumes final path may not be Lunix orientated
if (file_exists($filepath) && str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($filepath)) === str_replace('\\', '/', $filepath)) {
```

Answer (score -1):

On Windows, filenames are case-insensitive. That's just how they work.

So you need to manually code around this:

```
if( file_exists($file) && glob($file)[0] === $file) // assumes PHP 5.4
             // older versions need a temporary variable for glob
```

Comment: It didn't work. I tried to find profile in small characters but i got 404 error

Comment: Comment about filenames being case-insensitive in Windows is worth remembering.

Comment: This `glob` thing does nothing. It returns the provided casing, not the real from the file system. PHP 7 on Windows 10.